# C API Parametric datatypes, how?

Tags: z3

i'm using Z3 for my phd thesis. In a first attempt i just used the smtlibparse function for convenience since i had my formulas converted to smtlib format.

Now I wanted to use the api, since converting formulas to smtlib formated strings, and then parse them with z3 is a bit cumbersome and has slow performance.

I started to look at the api and I couldn't found how I can define parametric datatypes like this one

```
(declare-datatypes (T) ((Ref (mk-ref (inner T)))))
```

I would appreciate your help,

Comment: Did you have a look at the C API examples? They are here: https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#examples/c/test_capi.c They contain, among others, the tree_example and forest_example, which show how to construct a datatype via the C API.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger, thanks for the examples. I've seen them now, but they are build using always the same type. I mean they are not parametric/generic. What i would like is to have the datatype for multiple sorts for example a List[T], where T can be Int, Bool, Array, ....

In my specific case is for Ref but the same applies. Ref[Int], Ref[Bool], Ref[Array], Ref[Ref[Int]], etc.

Comment: The parameters in the SMT-LIB format is basically syntactic sugar. Every time you use a data-type it has to be instantiated with types. The programmatic API does not expose a shorthand for parametric data-types. Instead you would have to write a wrapper, e.g., a function that takes as input your parameters and returns a data-type. This should not be too roundabout if you have a real programming language.